# Get the longest element of a list

Tags: r, list

Suppose you have a list of data.frames like

```
dfs <- list(
  a = data.frame(x = c(1:4, 7:10), a = runif(8)),
  b = data.frame(x = 1:10, b = runif(10)),
  c = data.frame(x = 1:10, c = runif(10))
)
```

I would now like to extract the longest data.frame or data.frames in this list. How?

I am stuck at this point:

```
library(plyr)
lengths <- lapply(dfs, nrow)
longest <- max(lengths)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two built-in functions in R that could solve your question in my opinion:

1. `which.max`: returns the index of the **first** element of your list that is equal to the max

   ```
   > which.max(lengths)
   [1] 2
   ```
2. which function returns all indexes that are TRUE
   Here:

   ```
   > which(lengths==longest)
   [1] 2 3
   ```

Then you can subset you list to the desired element:

```
dfs[which(lengths==longest)]
```

will return b and c in your example.

Comment: @RichardScriven : You're absolutely right, however the title suggests that only one element should be returned ("the longest"). Maybe I did not highlight enough the **first** in my answer. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 4):

```
cnt <- sapply(dfs, nrow)
dfs[cnt == max(cnt)]
```

Or if you only need the first occurrence of the maximum length:

```
dfs[which.max(cnt)]
```

Comment: or use the which.max function to subset your list. `dfs[which.max(cnt)]`

Comment: OP said "data frame or data frames" so use of `which.max` is wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right. `which.max`, will only give the first hit.

Comment: Didn't know about which.max and it turns out in this case which.max is just what I need. Saves me one additional line of code. Thanks!